# dimens.xml in values folder for 7" and 10" tablet, how to?

Tags: android, xml, resources, dimensions

I have tried with:

```
values-mpdi, values-land-mpdi, values-hpdi and values-land-hdpi
```

which works fine in phone's screens, the problem is that it could happen that a 7" tablet takes the value from values-mdpi and a 10" tablet too, but the result is not the same, I guess because of the screen size (although is the same resolution and similar density)
so I tried:

```
values-sw600dp-hdpi
values-sw600dp-port-hdpi
values-sw600dp-mdpi
values-sw600dp-port-mdpi
values-sw720dp-hdpi
values-sw720dp-port-hdpi
values-sw720dp-mdpi
values-sw720dp-port-mdpi
```

but the app crashes because it does not find the resource needed....

any help will be much appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: for checking out screen parameters on individual devices, I've found the DisplayInfo app to be really handy: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.gerdavax.displayinfo

Answer (score 17):

Basically three main device categories exist that Android applications need to support:

1. handsets (phones)
2. small tablets (7″ category)
3. large tablets (10″ and above).

**Qualifiers before Android 3.2:**

Google’s **first** attempt at creating **qualifiers** to separate resources by device was to create a handful of size buckets: **small, normal, large, xlarge**. Initially, this worked out well as **handset** devices were in the small/normal category, the first **7″ tablets** on the market were large, and the first **10″ tablets** were xlarge.

**Qualifiers with Android 3.2 onwards:**

However, as more and more devices began appearing in the market with new screen sizes and the lines began to blur about where a device might present itself. **A new solution to the problem was presented in Android 3.2**, in the form of **new qualifiers** to pick resources based on a devices current width/height or **“smallest” width**; the latter being a new designation for the devices size by representing it in terms of the width (in density-independent pixels, or dp) of the shortest side of the screen.

Using the new paradigm, it has become common to define small tablets as having a smallest width of 600dp, and large tablets at 720dp, with handsets being everything that falls below that line.

**Using qualifiers when minimum support is below 3.2 and target is higher than or equal to 3.2**
For applications targeting Android 3.2 or higher as a minimum this new system works well. However, if developers wishing to create an application that runs universal on handsets and tablets are compelled to support a minimum Android version no higher than 2.2, or at best 2.3, then in that case create duplicates of each resource in a directory with the old size qualifier and place it an another directory with a corresponding smallest width qualifier.

E.g. keeping the same `dimens.xml` file in `values-large` and `values-sw600dp`. So the device running on android version lower than 3.2 will take values from `values-large` and the device running on android version higher than or equal to 3.2 will take values from `values-sw600dp`

Answer (score 3):

//you need to run this in API level 3.2 and above.

for the <3.2 you need to declare normal values-large and values-xlarge

Comment: Do you mean if I set `targetSDKVersion` to 19 then I need to use `values-sw600dp` and `values-sw720dp` and when I target to API below API level 13 then I need to use values-large and values-xlarge. right ?