# Android layout design using values folder i.e. style or dimen

Tags: android, android-layout

How to design proper layout or provide different margin,width and height for two different device i.e 3.2'' HVGA Slider (ADP1) (320X480;mdpi) and Nexus One (3.7'',480X800;hdpi) using values folder, because both devices access same value folder but look is not same.

Comment: have a look at this question may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android

Comment: I have already checked it but not working,because both devices access same value folder i.e.values-sw320dp

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) both devices will really access the same folder.
I had similar issue some time ago and I used this code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

and after you can make conditions like

```
if(width>=320 && width<480){
    yourView.setTextSize(myTextSize); //or use LayoutParams to define more options
```

or use `switch/case` operator instead

This is how I solved it, but if you have many many view elements, could be not useful.