# Design layout to support multiple screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have searched a lot on this topic on internet and found some useful links but still not able to design UI that supports all device sizes and resolutions. I have read details about this topic from developers site [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) about smallest width technique. Currently i have followed [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android) In which i have created a single layout folder and setting dimensions for each screen density in different folders. Currently my res folder looks like this

[image: res]

I have created a single layout folder and defined its dimensions in default values folder for normal screen size (that is Nexus S 4.0inch 480x800 hdpi), then i have copied that dimen file in values-sw600dp folder and adjusted dimensions for tablet that is correctly picking up for 7inch tablet. But now i am trying to design for other handsets/devices like Galaxy Nexus 4.7inch 720x1280 xhdpi or other large size handsets like galaxy s3,s4 etc but have no clue how to do it. If i put dimen file into values-sw320dp-xhdpi folder to adjust it for Galaxy Nexus 4.7inch 720x1280 it also changes for normal(Nexus S 4.0inch 480x800 hdpi) screen. So i am really confused about these design qualifiers. Can anyone describe an exact way or standard method/layout hierarchy to support all screen sizes?

Comment: make sure you don't get confused with pixels and dp's. with a Galaxy Nexus 4.7 720x1280 xhdpi (so 2x), your smallest width is still less than 480dp

Comment: so it means for both Galaxy Nexus 4.7 720x1280 xhdpi and Nexus S 4.0inch 480x800 hdpi same folder would be used that is values-sw480dp?

Answer (score 1):

You might be confused with pixels and density-independent pixels (dp or dip).

Galaxy Nexus 720x1280 pixels xhdpi (2x)means 360x640 in dp values, so smallest width (sw) is 360.
Nexus S 4.0inch 480x800 hdpi (1.5x)has smallest width of 320

So both of these will get there values from values-sw320

Comment: ok now i have got your point, but is my approach of creating a single layout folder and have multiple values folder to support multiple screens is correct?

Comment: It depends on what you do. If your layout looks the same on all devices, just with other dimensions, it's correct. If you have a different layout on large tablets than you have on phones, for example multiple fragments on tablet and only one fragment on phone, then you should create different layout files

Answer (score 0):

Create different layout folders for different screen sizes such as layout-large,layout-small,  layout-xlarge,layout-xxlarge etc. But I don't know  which layout you have used in xml files.
Always try to use LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. Don't use pixels in xml files.

In Manifest add support-screens

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```