# How can I correctly resize the layout when the keyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

In Android I have reproduced the following layout :

[image]

In this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#94F734"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <include layout="@layout/header"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:paddingTop="96dp"
        android:background="#463779B3"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:text="title"
            android:layout_above="@+id/code"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/code"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Insert here "
            android:background="@drawable/back_item_edit"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="36dp">
            <requestFocus />

        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prova"
            android:layout_below="@id/code"
            style="@style/initialButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="Connect"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/code"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/code"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I click on "insert here" one problem appears : the layout is not correctly resized and doesn't fit in the little screen.

I thought to use a scrollview, but I don't know how to use it.

When the keyboard appears I would to show :

- header (if there is room)
- title (if there is room)
- insert here
- connect
- green part of layout (if there is room)
- keyboard

Is there a way to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

First, you specify a lot of parameters using "dpi", like:

```
android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
```

This does not work for dynamically sizing much of anything. You are requiring the heights to be a specific height regardless of the size of other elements on the screen.

To solve this problem you first need to move away from absolute measurements, and start using runtime measurements. Normally, you could simply use the "hdpi", "xhdpi", etc. folders to manage this, but the layout with a keyboard is a dynamic measure (at runtime).

You could use XML hints like a weighted `LinearLayout` to adjust to the screen based on the available size. You could also use java code to change the size of elements. But you cannot expect that the screen will display elements that are larger than the available space (which is the problem it is having now). Also, you will need to determine how the elements will be "squeezed" together.

EDIT:

To make different layouts have different margins, etc. based on the screen size/density, you should look at having folders for each screen density (i.e. a folder for "layout-xhdpi" for example).

Here are the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Including using "dimens" folders like here:

[Different values folders in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)

So you have a lot of options for handling dynamic screens sizes. But maybe the "easiest" for many situations (like yours, probably) is to use the `displayMetrics` and adjust your elements accordingly:

[getting the screen density programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

You can measure, resize, etc. Each element has different `LayoutParams` or other attributes that allows you to change them programmatically. You probably need to do searches for the particular things that you want to change.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer. How can I center the body with a certain margin without using dpi but using hdpi,xhdpi etc etc ? And how can change the size of element dinamically by code ? My goal is show at least the edit text and the connect button at all the screen resolutions

Answer (score 1):

You can use this property in your manifest file for your activity [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use adjustResize and adjustPan . With the asdjustResize the layout has resized in wrong way, and using "adjustPan" the keyboard only disappears using back button :(