# ImageView size for phones and tablets

Tags: android, android-imageview, dashboard, screen-density

I'm making something like a dashboard for my app. And everything fine except situation with ImageView size for diffrent device's screen inch.

*It looks fine on phones and devices 7" and less*

[image]

*But on devices more than 7" it's looking bad*

[image]

In all cases I used same size of ImageView - 50dp and I have generate MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI images

If I will use dimens I will get blured images because MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI images will be generated only for 50dp, but not for 100dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_size">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

But seems devices with 7" and more inch needs a little more image size, for example, 100dp.

I can't googling the solution. **Is it possible to make images looks bigger on 7"+ tablets while not creating extra code?**

Comment: Create multiple dimen files for tablet and phone.

Comment: You could create values depending on screen size.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669523/the-size-of-the-buttons-depending-on-the-screen-resolution

Comment: Naveen Tamrakar, I already tryied this method. If specify in dimen.xml various ImageView sizes it will lost image sharpness, image will look blurry

Comment: svenvdz, thanks for reply, but seems your link doesn't regards to this quastion. I want make tile icon bigger on tablet but without blurry effect

Comment: I know that I can use dimensions such as `<dimen name="image_size">300dp</dimen>` but how I can make all image sizes for every density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is surprising and very strange that no one could give an answer to this seemingly simple question. Well, accidentally I found a solution and it was just as simple

If you want show different image sizes for tablet and phones just create an `dimen` for it

**for phones we show small image with 50dp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_size">50dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**for tablet around 10" we show 2x size image with 100dp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_size">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then in ImageView tag specify size:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
    android:id="@+id/imgViewIcon"/>
```

And necessarily you must make images for phones for different density from original size 50dp and put them in MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI folders. For tablet make image with 100dp and also generate for different density, then put it in **drawable-wNNNdp-?dpi** folders, where **NNN** - screen width and **?** - **l, m, h, xh, xxh, xxxh** dpi. Exactly folders **drawable-wNNNdp-?dpi** is the answer

Answer (score -1):

Don't give fix size to imageview.Give imageview's height and width wrap_content in xml....

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img"
android:src="@drawable/splash"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't help.