# automatic switch textview size by display

Tags: java, android, formatting, text-size

Please I have problem with size in textView

I have .xml code, where I use linear/horizontal/frame layout and I have in layout some object (textview) and have same text in textviews.

I need switch text size according to Phone display.
but if I put 130dp is not good for small display.

little of my code

```
<LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:baselineAligned="false">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="2">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                    android:text="88"
                                    android:id="@+id/hlc"
                                    android:textSize="130dp"
                                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                                    android:gravity="end"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="10">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                        android:text="°"
                                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                                        android:textSize="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_weight="9"
                                        android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                        android:text="8"
                                        android:id="@+id/hld"
                                        android:textSize=     "@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                                            android:textStyle="bold"
                                            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                                    </LinearLayout>

                                </LinearLayout>
```

if i use @android:dimen/thumbnail_width it's too big for my formated display

I need to fill in framelayput with text in textview.

I can't put image here :(

... and how are used values-small, values-large, etc ? example please. example declarate and example use in xml.

Thanks.

Comment: Create dimension values for different size and put them in the respective folders like: values-small, values-large, etc http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Hope it helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android

Comment: ... and how are used values-small, values-large, etc ? 
example please. 
example declarate and example use in xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create different dimension folder for different size with different `sp` (better to use `sp` than `dp` for text size).

check this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) for better understatement

and also check [this](http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/appendix-c-everything-about-sizes-and-dimensions-in-android/)

Comment: ... and how are used values-small, values-large, etc ? 
example please. 
example declarate and example use in xml.