# How to make different android values folders

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing an application where i need to set different font size for texts. So i created multiple dimens.xml in different values-XX folders.
How I have a case where I need to set different font sizes for two devices:

Motorola XT 1022 : 540px X 960px 4.2 inch density ~ 256

Micromax Bolt Q335 : 480px X 854px 4.5 inch density ~ 217

Which folders do I need to create so as to set font sizes?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android

Comment: i think both are hdpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Micromax Bolt Q335 : 480px X 854px 4.5 inch density ~ 217

Require to create folder "values-sw320dp-xhdpi" and put dimension

Comment: I have already defined all the value folder and check which value folder is support for which size.and put dimension base on folder.

Comment: bhai .do u have a list of the value folders i need to make to have maximum support on desi devices? anooppkrishnan6@gmail.com

Comment: sorry but hear i am list out please check it,

Comment: values-hdpi,values-mdpi,values-sw320dp-xhdpi,values-sw380dp,values-sw380dp-xhdpi,values-sw400dp,values-sw600dp-hdpi,values-sw600dp-mdpi,values-sw600dp-tvdpi,values-sw600dp-xhdpi,values-sw720dp-hdpi,values-sw720dp-mdpi,values-sw720dp-tvdpi,values-w820dp,values-xhdpi,values-xxhdpi,values-xxxhdpi

Comment: I think this may be enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to measure your device dimensions in DP. I think both of your devices are hdpi so the dimensions will be for example:

Motorola XT 1022: 360x640

then you can add folder:

```
values-360x640
```

Comment: yes that's it but it is not a very good way to have device specific approach. Instead use values-hdpi values-mdpi etc