# Values folders for specific android versions

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm just starting to get into material design for android and I ran into small problem - material design guide says to create separate values-v21 folder and create my custom theme there, while all older versions will fall back to default values folder. By the time tutorial was released 21 Android version was the latest, so do I need separate folders for each subsequent android versions (22,23..) now and just copy same theme? Or will all later version will fall back to v21 theme if there's no newer version values folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different values folders in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only create a `/values/` and a `/values-v21/` folder for your styles. `/values/` will be used by Android 4 and below, while `/values-v21/` will be used by Android 5 and above.

If both folders exist with proper `Styles.xml` files, then Android 5 and above devices will use `values-v21` and Android 4 and below devices will use `values`

Comment: This is a duplicate questions you should't answer it. Instead you should mark it as duplicate and point to the atual answer in stackoverflow.

Comment: @jzeferino I certainly would have done that if I would have known it was a duplicate. You marked it as such after I had already answered it.

Comment: However this question focuses on newer versions, than the link you provided @jzeferino . This question was more relevant to answering my question, where your link would still leave me unsure.

Comment: Answer is wrong. `values-v21` is used by Android 5 and *above*, not *below*.

Comment: @6rchid Fixed the versions and made it more clear what i was trying to say.