# Testing Mobile App on specify tablet

Tags: android, testing, tablet, screen-resolution

i've developed an android application for tablet and my question is:

How can i test my android application on tablet `7 inch widescreen` and what is the **real screen resolution** for this tablet ?

Comment: Tried USB debugging?

Comment: 7 inch tablet resolution is different  600*1024 and 1280*700 and many more so thats depend on screen resolution

Comment: i want a tablet 7 inch widescreen what is the density for this tablet?

Comment: @MohammedAtif i don't have a real device

Comment: Tablets in market range from low cost 320p tablets to high cost 4k tablets. Its better to test in least and max screen res custom emulators

Answer (score 0):

Please Create 7 Inch tablet Emulator and install your application in emulator 
that perfect way to testing our application when we don't have tablet device.

Comment: but i want a widescreen tablet what is the density ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify different dimens.xml in different folder for each of your screen, for example text size or width and height. For more explanation you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)