# Supporting multiple size of screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, screen-resolution

In my app i use Appbarlayout many times but the problem is when i run app in devices have resolution approx 480*720 the app bar layout cover whole screen

But in other high resolution devices it seems good

Not in appbarlayout also in navigation header height and other layout height.

How to fix this problem so that app seems good in low resolution as well as high resolution devices.

and also i want my app make tablet support. Tablets were so wide and looks weird in that also... Can some one help

**Any answers will highly appreciated**

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your dimension under value folder. You need to create sub folder folder under VALUE section and put your dimensions under it. Please refer below links for more details it will solve your problem.

1. [Different values folders in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)
2. http://www.tothenew.com/blog/handle-multiple-screen-sizes-in-android/
3. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
4. https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html