# How To Support Screen 1080 x 2160 (One plus 5 T) 401 PPi ?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I try various option for One Plus 5 like

values-xhdpi
values-xxhdpi 
drawable-xxhdpi

but didn't reflect text size and drawable? So what should be the values folder for dimens file and drawable for resolution 1080 X 2160?

Comment: refer http://screensiz.es/phone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android

Comment: @SANU - how did you keep the dimes for this resolution?

Comment: @SANU - do you got any solutions for this?? I am fetching same issue with 1080*2160 Asus Device.