# Autosizing default shapes

Tags: java, android, autosize

I need my app shows a white rectangle from below by clicking a button.
Is there a way to set its size and padding automatically, so it can fill perfectly on all type of devices?
This is my XML code, that permits a rectangle to slide from below:

XML:

```
<ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/viewtab"
  android:layout_width="359dp"    <!-- I'd like it autosized with padding-->
  android:layout_height="75dp" /> <!-- I'd like it autosized with padding-->
```

Java:

```
Vtab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewtab);
Vtab.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add one library like

add below dependency into app level gradle file ..

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

then after give size like below code ..

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewtab"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_359sdp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_75sdp" />
```

then same size all device.

Comment: It works after implementation into app level gradle file, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Shortcut:**

May be you can try below library which manages all the screen size resolution automatically.

`compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'`

You need to just add the dependency in your `build.gradle` file and you are done.

You need to specify like:

`android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"`

Instead of:

`android:layout_height="@dimen/10sdp"`

**Second way:**

Using Android [PercentRelativeLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsXds.png) like

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewtab"
        android:layout_width="80%"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50%"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelative
```

**Third long way:**

You have to create ***Different values folder for different screens*** .
Like

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi           5.5" 1440x2560 xxxhdpi

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

[image]

For more information you may visit here

> [Different values folders in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)
>
> http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

**Plugin to auto generate dimens**

You can make use of Android Studio plugin called [Dimenify](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio/plugin/9349-dimenify) to auto generate dimension values for other pixel buckets based on custom scale factors. Its still in beta, be sure to notify any issues/suggestions you come across to the developer.