# How to create values folder for particular screen size in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I have two wear device first device resolution is 240*240 hdpi and another device resolution is 280*280 hdpi. both are pointing hdpi  i need  create paritucular values  folder for 240*240 device.

Comment: check this once
[link, it will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the values directory/package like this

```
values-sw280dp
```